# What is the Least Prime Factor of $3^{3241} + 8^{2433}$

Tags: congruences, prime-factorization

I'm not sure how to do this question

**Attempt**
$$3^{3241} + 8^{2433}$$
I start by taking this number mod 3
$$3^{3241} + 8^{2433} \equiv 8^{2433} \mod 3$$
No we can see that $8^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$. So
$$8^{2433} \equiv 8 * (8^2)^{1216} \equiv 8 * 1^{1216}  \equiv 8 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

Ok So I know that the number is 2 mod 3. Therefore, it doesn't divide 3. I need to find the smallest prime number that will divide the number. Where do I go from here?

Thanks SE

Answer (score 1):

A quick python script shows that $4283$ is a divisor of this number, and is the smallest non-trivial divisor.

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+(3%5E3241+%2B+8%5E2433)) also gives this factor, and stops there.

Comment: Thanks. However, is there some way to do these types of questions mathematically? I've got a homework problem to do. It's not the one that I've asked above but something similar. I was hoping to find a method to solving these types of rpoblems

Comment: Sometimes the numbers are of special forms and one can do some tricks; I seem to recall that Koblitz's book on number theory is a good reference for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

By running the following program, the first prime that divides x can be found.

```
x = 3**3241 + 8**2433
i = 2
while x % i != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

> >> 4283

Although I was going to post it as a comment, I wanted to show my code used to retrieve the answer which cannot be posted in a comment. It should also be noted that $4283$ cannot be written as $3^i + 8^j$ for integers $i$ and $j$.